# Laravel send post request to another subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

I have a Laravel application where I have the main app set up, and I have a subdomain that handles a specific task related to main app.

Let's say main app is: **app.xyz.com**
and subdomain is: **review.xyz.com**

The question is, how can I send a post request from a controller in **review.xyz.com** to a route in **app.xyz.com**?

Here's what I have tried using Guzzle, which just silently failed (the response was just the login screen of main app. Nothing happened in the log):

```
Route::post('approve', function(){
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => env("MAIN_APP_URL")]);

    $response = $client->request('POST', 'public/approve');
    $body = $response->getBody();

    return $body;
});
```

How does the CSRF protection work in this case?

Comment: Do the user has to be logged in to go to the `public/approve` route? This would explain why it redirects you to the login page.

Comment: Are these two separate applications or the same app with subdomain routing?

Comment: @mimo Actually no, it isn't set up to use any middleware, so my guess is maybe the CSRF token mismatch exception is making the redirect.

Comment: @DavidBarker these are set up so they are treated like two separate applications.

Comment: @SeyongCho Ok cool, so next question: Do they have separate authentication or do they use the same session?

Comment: @DavidBarker both of them don't require authentication. They also do not use same session. The only thing is that they are hosted on the same server (Laravel forge & AWS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if calling to another json api, will not use csrf. Instead, we use api token such as **jwt** and laravel **api_token**. Thus, in your guzzle, you will be adding header for authorization.

```
$client->request('GET', 'example.com/get', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer your-long-api-token',
        'Accept'     => 'application/json'
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, solved it by disabling csrf on these routes and just forwarding the post parameters with guzzle. Going to look into your suggested apis to protect these routes

Comment: @SeyongCho move your endpoints to `routes/api.php` instead of using routes/web.php` (laravel 5.3+)

Comment: here is the reference for api_token https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51

Comment: Thanks! In this case it seems it makes more sense to put it in apis instead.